# Reuse backgroundworker in a for loop

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I want to reuse a backgroudworker MAX_RUNS times. I use the following code:

```
BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker1 = new BackgroundWorker();
backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
backgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
for (int run =1; run <=MAX_RUNS; run++)
{
        backgroundWorker1.DoWork += (s, args) =>
        {
           // Time consuming DLL call
        };
        backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged;
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted += backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted;
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        while (backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)
        {
            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(time, "TIME");
            Application.DoEvents();
        }
        backgroundWorker1.DoWork -= (s, args) =>
        {
           // Time consuming DLL call
        };
        backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged -= backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged;
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted -= backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted;
}
```

It works but the only problem is that the backgroundworker runs 2*MAX_RUNS times. What could be the reason for this strange behavior?

EDIT1: Moved RunWorkerAsync after RunWorkerCompleted. Still the same problem.

EDIT2: Added @Crono's suggestion. Still the same.

Comment: Not sure if has anything to do with your problem, but putting the call to RunWorkerAsync before setting up the ProgressChanged event and RunWorkerCompleted event doesn't seem to be very logical.

Comment: And you are subscribing to multiple DoWork handlers without unsubscribe, and that's why it runs x*MAX_RUNS times.

Comment: The code runs just fine even when RunWorkerAsync is after ProgressChanged event and RunWorkerCompleted.

Comment: @Bolu What do you mean by unsubscribe. Sorry I am new to C#.

Comment: You are adding a new event handler on every loop, meaning the handler gets executed multiple times. You need to set `backgroundWorker.Event -= EventHandler` somewhere.

Comment: @Crono I implemented your suggestion. The problem persists.

Comment: I actually meant to explain what "unscribing" was. :)

Comment: It's pointless to use a BGW in the first place if all you're going to do is sit there blocking the UI thread in the first place.  You absolutely should *not* be doing that.  You're defeating the entire purpose of using a BGW.  You need to let the UI thread exit the method and continue executing, so that it can continue to pump UI operations.

Comment: My UI thread is not getting blocked. I am able to use all buttons on the UI while the DLL is executing. The progress bar also updates perfectly.

Comment: @Prometheus You're only creating a maintenance *nightmare* for yourself by using `DoEvents`.  It will appear to do what you want in simple tests, and cause all sorts of havoc when things start to get more complicated, and it will happen in ways that are extremely unintuitive, and that will be virtually impossible to diagnose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no real *reason* to try to re-use the background worker.  Creating one is not expensive at all, and you're not gaining anything here by trying to re-use the same one.

As for why you're method is firing so many times, you're not properly unsubscribing from the event.  The lambda that you subscribe is a delegate with a different object instance and method pointer than the delegate you unsubscribe; since you fail to unsubscribe the events, it fires 1 event the first run, 2 the second run, 3 the third run, etc. for `n*(n+1)/2` total methods fired.

Additionally you're trying to wait in the UI thread for the worker to finish.  You shouldn't be doing this.  It's contrary to the entire asynchronous model.

If you want to use a BGW you should be creating and starting an entirely new worker each time the previous worker is completed (if you're not done).  You could also greatly simplify the program by using the TPL instead:

```
public async void Foo(IProgress<T> progress)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_RUNS; i++)
    {
        await Task.Run(() => TimeConsumingMethodCall());
        WhateverYoureDoingWhenEachWorkerCompletes();
        progress.Report(time);
    }
    UpdateUIWithFinalResults();
}
```

Comment: This answer worked for me. I can now do it without using Application.DoEvents().

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not adding / removing `DoWork` handlers properly.

The first added handler correspond to a unique lambda expression. When you are unsubscribing, you are doing it on a brand new lambda expression. Therefore the first handler never gets removed, and a new one gets added on every run.

Try replacing your lambda expression with an actual method. It might solve your problem. And even if it doesn't that's what you really should do.

Comment: I use a lambda expression because the DLL is provided to me. I don't have its source code.

Comment: Your current code exists within a class of yours, right? What prevents you from defining a static method on it that has the exact same signature as your lambda expression and call the exact same code it would?